# Getting {% load chartit %} on my browser. Charts are not loading using chartit

Tags: html, django, highcharts

I am Displaying graphs using `Django Chartit` and `Cassandra 3.0` is my database.

I have tried to render a line chart but it's not showing a graph, instead it's showing `{% load chartit %}`. Please suggest something. I have googled but it's not helpful.

I think the code in HTML is correct. But I dont have a clue what is going wrong.

Below are supplements:

**Models.py**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from django_cassandra_engine.models import DjangoCassandraModel


class PqpModel(DjangoCassandraModel):

    prd_id = columns.BigInt(primary_key=True)

    X_01 = columns.Decimal()

    X_02 = columns.Decimal()

    X_03 = columns.Decimal()

    X_04 = columns.Decimal()

    X_05_1 = columns.Decimal()

    X_05_10 = columns.Decimal()

    X_05_11 = columns.Decimal()

    X_05_12 = columns.Decimal()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.db import models

from cassandra.cqlengine import connection

from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

from chartit import DataPool, Chart

from models import PqpModel

from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse

# def index(request):
#     cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
#     session = cluster.connect()
#     session.set_keyspace('samplepqp')
    #return HttpResponse(session.execute("""SELECT * FROM qsp_recreate"""))
   # insert = PqpModel(prd_id="7859654564465465")
   # insert.save()
   #  cluster.shutdown()

def pqp_line_chart(request):
        cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
        session = cluster.connect()
        session.set_keyspace('samplepqp')
        cluster.shutdown()
        #1: Create a DataPool or PivotDataPool object that specifies what data you need to retrieve and from where.
        ds = DataPool(
            series=[{'options': {
                'source': PqpModel.objects.all()},
                'terms': [
                    'prd_id',
                    'X_01',
                    'X_05_1']}
            ])

        # Step 2: Create the Chart object

        cht = Chart(

            datasource=ds,

            series_options=
            [{
                'options': {

                    'type': 'line',
                    'stacking': False},
                'terms': {
                    'prd_id': [
                        'X_01',
                        'X_05_1']

                }}],

            chart_options=
            {'title': {
                'text': 'QSPRAW DATA 7'},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                        'text': 'prd id data'}}})

        #return render({'qspraw7_data/index.html': cht})

        return render(request, {'pqpchart': cht})
```

**index.html**

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script type=”text/javascript” src=”/media/js/jquery-1.7.1.js”></script>
 <script type=”text/javascript” src=”/media/js/Highcharts-2.1.9/js/highcharts.js”></script>
 {% load chartit %}

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id=”container”>
     {{ pqpChart|load_charts:”container” }}
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML template should look like:

```
<head>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/media/js/jquery-1.7.1.js”></script>
 <script type=”text/javascript” src=”/media/js/Highcharts-2.1.9/js/highcharts.js”></script>
 {% load chartit %}
 {{ pqpChart|load_charts:"container" }} 
</head>
<body>
 <div id=”container”>
 </div>
</body>
```

and then the view should return the proper variable, with case sensitive names. In you example use the same capitalization you use in the HTML template:

```
return render(request, {'pqpChart': cht})
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have made changes according to ur suggestions. But  charts are not rendering, I am getting this in my browser: "{% load chartit %} {{ pqpChart|load_charts:"container" }}" please shed some light.

Comment: any more suggestions please!

Comment: I am now getting --> in my browser, very strange!